# How to fix unnecessary space in Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a `Constraint Layout`. The objective is to stack two `recyclerview`s on top of each other. The reason I am using a `Constraint Layout` is because I also want a `TextView` to occupy the same space as the bottom `recyclerview`. (I will programatically set the `TextView` to be visible when the bottom `recyclerview` has no content).

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@color/heart_red"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tabRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/imageRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/lightshade"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tabRecyclerView" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, here is the layout for the item column in my `imageRecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkshade">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/itemFavoriteButton"/>

    <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/itemProgressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/itemFavoriteButton"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/itemFavoriteButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, for some reason there is a red bar on the bottom of the `Constraint Layout`, like so:

[image: Screenshot Of Phone]

As far as I can tell, mathematically, everything checks out. So why is there a red bar at the bottom of my layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to stack the recyclerviews on top of each other, right?

Currently, You can't sum the heights of tabRecyclerView and imageRecyclerView because they are overlapping each other.

**Check this out**

- The parent layout height is 250dp
- The tabRecyclerView is 50dp
- The imageRecyclerView is 200dp (but because of this line `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tabRecyclerView"`, its overlapping tabRecyclerView)
- Missing 50dp (which is why the red background from the parent is showing up)

**To fix**

change

`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tabRecyclerView"`

to

`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabRecyclerView"`